# "near then expecting <= " what is this error?

Tags: compare, vhdl

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Division is
port (
    A          : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    B          : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Remind     : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Errorsig   : out std_logic;
    Ready      : out std_logic);
end entity Division;

architecture Behavioural of Division is
    component fullsubstractor4 is
        port (
            a       : IN  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            b       : IN  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            bor_in  : IN  std_logic;
            diff    : OUT std_logic_vector;
            bor_out : OUT std_logic);
    end component;

    component fulladder 
        port (
            a   : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            b   : IN  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            cin : IN  std_logic;
            c   : OUT std_logic;
            s   : OUT std_logic_vector (3 downto 0));
    end component;

    signal AA,BB,Q,R,temp_0,temp_1,temp_2,temp_3 :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000";
    signal temp_4, temp_5: std_logic; ------- (Carry and Borrow only 1 bit)

begin

fs1: fullsubstractor4
  port map (AA, BB,'0', temp_1, temp_4);

fs2: fullsubstractor4
  port map (temp_1, BB, '0', temp_2, temp_4);

fa1: fulladder
   port map (Q, "0001",'0', temp_5, temp_3);

division: process
    begin
        AA <= A;
        BB <= B;
        If BB = "0000" then 
           Errorsig <= '1';
        elseif (AA < BB) then
           Q <= "0000";
           R <= AA;
        elseif (AA = BB) then
           Q <= "0001";
           R <= "0000";
        elseif (AA > BB) then
           Q <= "0001";
           R <= temp_1;
           while temp_1 > BB loop
               Q <= temp_3; 
               R <= temp_2;
               temp_1 <= temp_2;
               wait for 10 ns;
           end loop;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioural;
```

For this code of division I am getting error as 'near then expecting "<=" or ":="' on the line where I am comparing two std_logic_vectors.
For Line (in process) I am getting this error while compiling.

Comment: What language are you working in? And where's the code?

Comment: Just check I have edited the script

Comment: Not nice. Questions are useless later on when they get crippled after they have been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elseif` isn't a VHDL reserved word, so the compiler thinks it's an identifier such as a signal name, then expects an assignment to it...

Try `elsif` instead.

And find a better VHDL syntax reference...

Fru1tbat's answer is overall better, but this describes why the specific error message occurred.

Answer (score 1):

First, `elseif` is not the proper keyword for VHDL. It's `elsif`.

Second, comparison operators like `>` have no meaning to `std_logic_vector`s, which are ordinarily treated just as arrays of bits, not numeric representations. You should ideally be including `ieee.numeric_std` and casting as a numeric vector type (`signed` or `unsigned`) in your comparison, like:

```
elsif unsigned(AA) > unsigned(BB) then
```

(If you'd rather not cast over and over, using intermediate signals or variables will also work, but casting is probably the cleanest option)

That should get you a little further.

Comment: True, but that would require changing all the components as well, so I decided on a simpler suggestion...

Comment: Fair point. But I WOULD change the components too, (or at least seriously consider it) since they will suffer the same issue internally. Better to USE the type system correctly from the start than fight it everywhere...